# Prove the inequality $\frac{(a+c)^{2}}{ad+bc}+\frac{(b+d)^{2}}{ac+bd}+4\geq 4\left ( \frac{a+b+1}{c+d+1}+\frac{c+d+1}{a+b+1} \right)$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c+d=2$. Prove the inequality: 
$\frac{(a+c)^{2}}{ad+bc}+\frac{(b+d)^{2}}{ac+bd}+4\geq 4\left ( \frac{a+b+1}{c+d+1}+\frac{c+d+1}{a+b+1} \right)$ 
I came across this problem in an online lecture, the presenter gave us this problem as an exercise to do at home. I haven't been able to solve it, but u have some ideas I don't think work. 
First, I thought about distributing the $4$ across the fractions, so we would get
$\frac{(a+c)^{2}}{ad+bc}+\frac{(b+d)^{2}}{ac+bd}+4=\frac{a^2+c^2+2ac+2ad+2bc}{ad+bc}+\frac{b^2+d^{2}+2bd+2ac+2bd}{ac+bd}$
The thing is, I got two $2bd$ in the second fraction, so it isn't kind of cyclic like I thought it would be, or at least similar to the first fraction. I have been stuck on this problem since then and don't know how to continue, maybe  I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [CS inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$\frac{(a+c)^2}{ad+bc}+\frac{(b+d)^2}{ac+bd}+\frac{2^2}1\geqslant \frac{(a+c+b+d+2)^2}{(a+b)(c+d)+1}$$

It remains to show that for $a+b=x\in (0, 2)$,
$$\frac{16}{x(2-x)+1} \geqslant 4\left(\frac{x+1}{3-x} +\frac{3-x}{x+1}\right)$$
$$\iff 4(3-x)(x+1)\geqslant (x(2-x)+1)((x+1)^2+(3-x)^2)$$
$$\iff 2(x-1)^4\geqslant 0$$

Comment: I don't really get how you got that the inequality that follows from CS inequality is bigger or equal to the wanted inequality...

Comment: $ \frac{(a+c+b+d+2)^2}{(a+b)(c+d)+1} \geq 4\left ( \frac{a+b+1}{c+d+1}+\frac{c+d+1}{a+b+1} \right)$.

Comment: I don't understand how to prove it...

Comment: @Loki Substitute $a+b=x$, so that $c+d = 2-x$, and you can write everything as a one variable inequality (as shown in the post).  The rest is just multiplication and expanding terms.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but how do you know that the inequality that follows from CS is bigger or equal to the wanted one?

Comment: $\frac{(a+c+b+d+2)^2}{(a+b)(c+d)+1} \geq 4\left ( \frac{a+b+1}{c+d+1}+\frac{c+d+1}{a+b+1} \right)$

Comment: How do you prove this inequality?

Comment: Because this inequality is not the same as the inequality in the problem.

Comment: @Loki Make the substitutions I mentioned, it becomes exactly the same inequality.  If you still have trouble seeing it, post what you get after replacing $a+b$ and $c+d$ with $x$ and $2-x$.

Comment: Ouuuuuuuuu I get it now. Thank you I am a little slow! Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: No worries, we all get stuck from time to time.